# Past simple/progressive

Tags: sentence-meaning

Can we use the past simple instead of the past progressive in the following sentence:

> I thought we *were saying* goodbye forever, but we were to meet again, many
>   years later, under very strange circumstances.

This sentence is provided as an example for *to be + infinitive* structure. Since there is no more context I can provide.

Comment: Past simple will serve the purpose, I think. In fact, it looks better to me.

Comment: Probably not, for the example seems to be from a novel, where it was using past-tense narrative mode. This means that currently in the scene that is being dramatized, the narrator **is saying** goodbye to someone with the assumption that the goodbye is forever--that is what the narrator is currently thinking at that moment as the scene is unfolding in front of the reader; but then, the narrator goes on to tell the reader about a future event (they were to meet again), which means that the story is using a reminiscent narrator--but that is a different topic from what you are asking about. :)

Comment: @F.E. Why don't you post this as an answer? If it stays as a comment, the question will stay unanswered because people won't repeat what you have already said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, we can use the past simple instead of the past progressive in the sentence, but there'll be a difference in meaning. If we use the past progressive, it means that the thought came to the speaker in the middle of saying goodbye. On the other hand, if we use the past simple, it means the thought came to him after they said goodbye.